# Why are bots in CS-GO frozen in spawn, in online match with friend?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

A couple of months ago, I was able to play CSGO with my friend online 2vs5bots. Since an update (beginning January 2021) bots were taken away from online games in CS-GO. Unfortunately, when I now want to play with a friend online vs bots, they just stay frozen at the spawn. It is also not possible to add more than three to the opponent team (mp_teamautobalance = 0, mp_limitteams = 1 don't help). No comments with bot_... did work. Is there a way to play with a friend online vs 5 bots? It does still work in every other mode except 5on5.

Thanks!